# Mac Pro (Early 2008) - Unable to print in color to HP 4730 MFP

Tags: printing, mac-pro, driver, third-party

When I print from a Mac Pro (Early 2008) running El Capitan (10.11.6) to a HP 4730MFP, all my color prints come out black and white. However when I print from my Lenovo running Win 10, they print just fine in color. The print driver for the machine is PCL v5.1. Somehow I feel the driver is not translating properly on the Mac side. I called MAC and they said they no longer support drivers for that machine. When I reset the printing system and re-add, it won't even work if I select the apple driver from the software drop down list. It gives an error code 49.4C06. It only works when I select the PCL Generic driver which unfortunately does not have the option to print in color.

Is there a workaround? Maybe a third party app that would work?

Comment: https://support.apple.com/en-gb/HT201465 says drivers should be built-in to the OS for that model. HP says the same - http://h20565.www2.hp.com/hpsc/doc/public/display?lang=en&cc=us&docId=emr_na-c01844177 Or maybe try current PCL drivers from Gimp - http://gimp-print.sourceforge.net/MacOSX.php

Comment: I do not see the HP 4730 mfp supported in the link to the GIMP drivers you listed.

Comment: Thanks Tetsujin. Is there another alternative I can explore?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This has been resolved. The generic postscript driver did the trick. PCL is device dependent which means that the drivers for this language utilize the printer hardware for creating some of the printed data, usually graphics data such as fill areas, underlines or fonts. PostScript on the other hand is a device-independent page description language developed by Adobe, which is used to print and display pictures and text. It is used heavily in Macintosh platforms and for graphic applications in several platforms. Hope that helps someone.