# MacOS won't print color on HP inkjet

Tags: macos, color, printing

When we bought our "HP ENVY 5000 Series 2," it did everything we expected.  But a few months later, unchecking the "black and white" box would still print black and white.  A few months after that, the checkbox no longer appears on the print dialogue.  The small preview in the print dialogue is always black and white.

If I save as PDF or as a screen image and sync it over to an iPad, the iPad prints in color.

[Mac Pro (Early 2008) - Unable to print in color to HP 4730 MFP](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/250294/mac-pro-early-2008-unable-to-print-in-color-to-hp-4730-mfp) suggests a Postscript driver, but I don't quite grasp all the details.

Neither Apple nor HP has responded, although the last time I contacted Apple was with another laptop.  Now I have one with AppleCare, so it might be worth calling them.  But they left me **highly** unimpressed regarding a problem with Mail.  (Hours of try this, hmm, try this, hmm, etc. and finally the guy declared it fixed when it wasn't and wouldn't respond when I said so).

This started with a 2012 MacBook and Catalina, and was still an issue with the 2018 MBP on Mojave and continued till now with the latest Big Sur on the 2019 MBP.  Been on WiFi all along—never been wired.

Answer (score 1):

1. If your printer is connected via USB: Disconnect it and connect it to your network
2. Open System Preferences
3. Open "Printers & Scanners"
4. Right-click in the Printer list on the left side
5. Click "Reset printing system..." (Warning: this will remove all printers from the list)
6. Click the Plus-symbol and select the HP Envy from the list
7. Select the HP Envy and make sure you use "AirPrint" in the drop-down list for drivers

Comment: It's been on WiFi all along